# Use iOS Framework with ASIHTTPRequest integrated in project with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created framework, that uses ASIHTTPRequest.

Than i added this framework into my project that already uses ASIHTTPRequest. And i got

> ld: duplicate symbol ...

What is the correct way in this situation?

Comment: Do not link your framework against ASIHTTPRequest. Make sure your framework has all ASI-Headers at reach (but not bundled) once building. Then, when building an app linking against your framework, make sure you also link against ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

objective C has no namespace support it will guess which class to use with undetermined results.
On the other hand, you should not be exposing internal headers from your framework, not sure if that is the cause.

Either way, you have to pick one option or rename all your private ASIHttpRequest classes to avoid the conflict.

If you know the dependency is available then just use it from a dependent framework.  This is just a build problem not a deal killer in most cases.

Comment: So, the right way is to rename all ASIHttpRequest classes (add prefix)? It's good solution, but in other hand you final application's bundle will have 2 copies of ASIHttpRequest.

Comment: no the right way is to build your product knowing what dependencies are already taken care of and not include stuff in your project included by other libraries

Comment: OK,nice,summary:
I developed framework. It uses some popular libs. In documentation i must write that it uses these libs, so, clients no need to connect them. Yes?